# Use field name variable in JQuery validation rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces, jquery-validate

I am a jquery newbie. I could get the validation rules working in my form. I am using a Java framework and for some reason, when it converts from .xhtml to .html, all the ui component's id/name were prefixed with the form that containing it. I would like to reuse these validation rules for two other forms but because of the prefix issue, I would need to use js variable and pass the formId to the function. For some reason, this gives me a problem:

---

### NOT WORKING

```
var positionTitle = "#myForm:positionTitle";

$("#" + formId).validate({

  rules:{
        positionTitle : {required:true, maxlength:50},
            ...
```

---

### WORKING

```
$("#" + formId).validate({

  rules:{
         "#myForm:positionTitle" : {required:true, maxlength:50},
              ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you call `.validate()` on the form, you an do this:

```
$("[name='" + positionTitle + "']").rules("add", {required:true, maxlength:50});
```

...but you can't use the variable as a name in an object literal like that.

The other option is constructing the `rules` object before it gets passed into `validate()`, but that gets a bit messy as well, I can't say which is better based on the question, but if you have many of these, you may want to go the `rules` building route.

Comment: @blu3_ros3: could you please post your solution if it differs from Nick's?